# Calling method from options function of jquery widget

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Iam creating some widget and need method in options like this (with possibility of calling _someMethod which is in same widget):

```
options: {
    afterLoad: function (count) {
        this._someMethod();
    }
}
_someMethod: function(){
}
```

But "this" in options have context only of options. How to call _someMethod() from options method afterLoad? How to get widget context on afterLoad method?

Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your function ( `method` ) as a variable and use it later in the object like this :

```
var someMethod = function() { ... };

options: {
    afterLoad: function (count) {
        someMethod();
    }
}
_someMethod: someMethod
```

By doing this you will assign a variable that you must define inside a function ( because you don't want to leak any global variables ) and use it as a reference in your options